# Kendo UI - Datepicker is not rendering inside Kendo-Template

Tags: templates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

We are trying to provide a Kendo Datepicker inside Grid expand Client Detail Template using Kendo template, below is the snipping we are trying:

```
<script id="templateUserDefinedFieldsHealthPlan" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div id="indider"> </div>
<input id="datePicker1" />
</script>

and the jquery script tp provide datepicker is mentioned below :
<script>
    $(() => {
        var template = kendo.template($("#templateUserDefinedFieldsHealthPlan").html());
        var result = template({});
        //alert(result);

        $('#indider').html(result);
        $('#datePicker1').kendoDatePicker();        
    });
</script>
```

but in spite of Kendo DatePicker, only blank textbox is rendering. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you placed the `<div id="indider"> </div>` element inside the template too. You need to place it outside the template to replace it with the template's content.

See the snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.2.619/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="indider"></div>

  <script id="templateUserDefinedFieldsHealthPlan" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input id="datePicker1" />
  </script>
  
<script>
  $(() => {
    var template = kendo.template($("#templateUserDefinedFieldsHealthPlan").html());
    var result = template({});
    //alert(result);

    $('#indider').html(result);
    $('#datePicker1').kendoDatePicker();        
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```